# Hibernate Search Projection - StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

The Hibernate Search documentation for using a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#d0e5787) gives the following example:

```
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery query = 
    s.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Book.class );
query.setProjection( "title", "mainAuthor.name" );
query.setResultTransformer( 
    new StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer( 
        BookView.class, 
        "title", 
        "author" ) 
);
List<BookView> results = (List<BookView>) query.list();
for(BookView view : results) {
    log.info( "Book: " + view.getTitle() + ", " + view.getAuthor() );
}
```

However, the `StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer` class does not exist in the Hibernate core jar.

Does anyone know if this is supposed to be a different class that I have not been able to identify yet? Or does it exist in another Hibernate project that I have not included?

I need to accomplish this idea of mapping indexed fields to properties in my "BookView" bean, since my properties and fields are not named the same. I am using Hibernate 4.1.8 and Hibernate Search 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no such class in Hibernate codebase. I believe it was part of the samples one day, but nowhere to be found since.

The easiest way is to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Right, there is no such class. See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1004608. Just write your own transformer by implementing *org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer*.